# What is the recommended rep to nominate self in moderator election to actually stand a chance of winning?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderator-election, moderators

There are pre-entry requirements to nominate self in a moderator election.

For example, the badges requirement ..

Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy, Convention

I understand that there is no rep requirement. But what, would you say, is the recommended rep to nominate self in a moderator election?

In particular, to actually stand any chance whatsoever of being elected, what in your opinion would be a good amount of rep to first achieve before standing - assuming all other entry requirements are satisfied.

EDIT: I understand the minimum rep requirement is 3k. Still interested however in what is a recommended rep.

Comment: There *is* a minimum rep requirement, you need 3k at minimum.

Comment: I'd hope that reputation is not the only thing voters look at. If you have a good track record participating on Meta and have actively participated by productive (qualitative) flagging, and show aptitude in the answered questions, you can nominate yourself at any reputation. Just take into account that if there are more than 30 nominees, only the top 30 *ordered by reputation* go through to the next round.

Comment: Other than what @MartijnPieters has stated I wouldn't say there is a _recommended rep_ it depends on how you got that rep, I'd rather a moderator who has answered 100 questions and participated in the site more with a lower rep than say one who has just asked a popular question.

Comment: Can't really predict how people will vote.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no recommended rep, though there is a minimal rep requirement (it opens at 3,000 but is dynamic - if all 30 candidates have more than that, it jumps to 1 over the minimum rep of the last place - because only the top 30 users by rep will go forward to the primaries).

The idea is that elections are open to any user in good standing and with the minimal reputation.